# python regex groups

Tags: python, regex

I'm fairly new to python and I'm trying to understand I do I loop regex groups, ex:

```
reobj = re.compile('<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>', re.IGNORECASE)
result = reobj.findall(body)
```

how do I loop the 2 groups from the regex ?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, "loop the groups"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the regex matches 2 groups (.*?) and I want to loop both groups.

Comment: Considering your example, you may also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I needed was:

```
reobj = re.compile('<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>', re.IGNORECASE)
result = reobj.findall(body)


for link in result:
        print link[0] + link[1]
```

Answer (score 6):

Did you actually try this in the shell?

```
>>> body = """<a href="http://foo.com">Foo</a><br><a href="http://bar.com">Bar</a>"""
>>> reobj = re.compile('<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> result = reobj.findall(body)
>>> result
[('http://foo.com', 'Foo'), ('http://bar.com', 'Bar')]
```

So the result of `findall` is simply a list of tuples containing the matched groups. If you don't know how to iterate through a list, then you need to do an introductory Python tutorial.

[insert standard rant about how you shouldn't use regex to parse HTML here...]